# XSLT: Replacing div with script on multiple levels

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to replace certain div-tags with script-tags within any level.
 The code within the div that is set to display none is what I need (discard the two outer divs), and the divs within that code that has a class of "is-script" must be replaced with script, while keeping its attributes and nodes.
Some examples of how the code can look:

```
 <div data-type="embed">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="is-script" src="http://example.js"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type="embed">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <div class="is-script" src="http://example1.js"></div>
        <div class="is-script" src="http://example2.js"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type="embed">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <div>
            <div class="is-script" src="http://example.js"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type="embed">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <div>
            <div class="is-script" src="http://example1.js"></div>
            <div class="is-script" src="http://example2.js"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type="embed">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <div>
            <div class="is-script" src="http://example1.js"></div>
            <div class="is-script">some inline javascript</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type="embed">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <iframe src="http://example.html" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

The actual json that the xsl is parsing:

```
<div data-type=\"embed\" style=\"width:545px;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;\">HTML EMBED
    <div style=\"display:none;\">
        <div class=\"is-script\">console.log(\"test1\");</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type=\"embed\" style=\"width:545px;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;\">HTML EMBED
    <div style=\"display:none;\">
        <div>
            <div class=\"is-script\">console.log(\"test2\");</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type=\"embed\" style=\"width:545px;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;\">HTML EMBED
    <div style=\"display:none;\">
        <div class=\"is-script\" src=\"example.js\"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type=\"embed\" style=\"width:545px;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;\">HTML EMBED
    <div style=\"display:none;\">
        <div>
            <div class=\"is-script\" src=\"example.js\"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-type=\"embed\" style=\"width:545px;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;\">HTML EMBED
    <div style=\"display:none;\">
        <div>
            <div class=\"is-script\" src=\"example1.js\"></div>
            <div class=\"is-script\" src=\"example2.js\"></div>
            <div class=\"is-script\" src=\"example3.js\"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Wanted result:

```
<script class="is-script" src="http://example.js"></script>


<script class="is-script" src="http://example1.js"></script>
<script class="is-script" src="http://example2.js"></script>


<div>
    <script class="is-script" src="http://example.js"></script>
</div>


<div>
    <script class="is-script" src="http://example1.js"></script>
    <script class="is-script" src="http://example2.js"></script>
</div>


<div>
    <script class="is-script" src="http://example1.js"></script>
    <script class="is-script">some inline javascript</script>
</div>


<iframe src="http://example.html" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Current result:

```
<script class="was-script-tag">console.log("test1");</script>

<div>
    <div class="was-script-tag">console.log("test2");</div>
</div>

<script class="was-script-tag" src="/templates/v1/js/sticky_article_v7.js?v0"></script>

<div>
    <div class="was-script-tag" src="/templates/v1/js/sticky_article_v7.js?v1"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="was-script-tag" src="/templates/v1/js/sticky_article_v7.js?v2"></div>
    <div class="was-script-tag" src="/templates/v1/js/sticky_article_v7.js?v2"></div>
    <div class="was-script-tag" src="/templates/v1/js/sticky_article_v7.js?v2"></div>
</div>
```

My xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@data-type='embed' or parent::div[@data-type='embed']]">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='is-script']">
        <script>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </script>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So basically remove two outer divs, and keep everyting inside as is, except divs with class of "is-script" which must be renamed to script. The two outer divs will always be the same.

I have a basic understanding of xsl, but this is something I just can't make work.
Using xslt 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly start off with the identity template, which will copy all existing nodes without change

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, to ignore the "outer two divs" you can add an overriding template like so:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@data-type='embed' or parent::div[@data-type='embed']]">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

This ignores `div` elements with a data-type of embed, or its immediate child div.

Then to change the "is-script" divs to `script` elements you can add another template

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='is-script']">
  <script>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </script>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div[@data-type='embed' or parent::div[@data-type='embed']]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div[@class='is-script']">
    <script>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </script>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is pretty much what I had done too, but it only replaces the div to script on top level. Meaning that all divs with class "is-script" inside a div is not transformed.
If you are positive this code should work, then I guess I must look at other factors.

Comment: The XSLT should generate the expected output you have in your question (after adding a single root element to your XML). Can you perhaps edit your question to show a sample XML where it is not providing the correct output? Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the post with more details. If its relevant: I am using Saxon parser. Page is made with jstl.
There are some minor differences with between the original simplified code and the actual json. I can edit the post to be exactly the same if its unclear what I am asking for.

Comment: I've adressed an issue that made the results unpredictable. It now seems to work as intended. Only thing is that the "html embed" node is not stripped. Thank you for your time, it helped me out greatly :)

Comment: If you want to ignore text nodes that literally contain the text "html embed", you could try adding another template match to the XSLT, like so: `<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space() = 'HTML EMBED']" />`

Comment: Thank you very much! Goal achieved :)